# Meta-analysis of time-to-event data for single group design

Tags: r, survival, meta-analysis, systematic-review

I would like to perform a meta-analysis of time-to-event data for a single group (i.e. there is no comparison group). How do I do so, what are the statistics required?

I understand that for 2-group studies, the effect sizes are hazard ratio and its variance.

I use the `meta` package in r for my meta-analysis and couldn't find one for time-to-event data.
https://bookdown.org/MathiasHarrer/Doing_Meta_Analysis_in_R/

Regards,
Hanis

Comment: I would generate a point estimate of effect and relevant variability measure (standard error) for median survival time, or % of patients alive at 12 months (for instance). Then you can use inverse variance weighting.

Comment: @Joe_74 Do you mean that I should just consider the proportion of patients still surviving beyond 12 months (for instance) as the effect measure? i.e. ignore the other components of survival data?

Comment: You can use any effect estimate (provided you factor in the approprite point estimate and its variance). In your case, you could use median survival (and corresponding variance). Otherwise it's fine you also use incidence of event (eg % of those with event at 12 months), just make sure you generate the appropriate variance.